# How can I dynamically add attributes to component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario in which I want to dynamically assign an attribute to my `PrivateRoute` component.

This is my component.

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
```

Here I want something like this:

```
<PrivateRoute {localStorage.getItem('user') ? exact : '' } path="/" component={HomePage} />
```

If the `localStorage.getItem('user')` is true then only `exact` should be applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the spread operator like this:

```
const exact = localStorage.getItem('user') ? { exact: true } : { };
<PrivateRoute {...exact} path="/" component={HomePage} />
```

If `getItem()` returns falsy then an empty object will be spread and no attribute will be set at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const user = localStorage.getItem('user');

user ? <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} /> 
     : <PrivateRoute path="/" component={HomePage} />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have an object `obj={a:'something', b:'somethingelse'}`, just pass it to the component like this:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} {...obj} />
```

So inside your component you can access to it by:

this.props.a, this.props.b etc etc